# How to Install Windows VPS on Centos with KVM?

Tags: windows, centos, vps

I have a server with KVM. Running Centos 5.

Can you show me install VPS Windows on this Server ?

Thanks.

Comment: not programming related (see superuser.com or serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Windows VPS can run on Cent OS. 
However, we're successful running CENT OS on Hyper-V Virtualized VPS.